# The smallest subgroup containing $ (1, 2) $ and $(1, 2, 3.,\ldots,n) $ is $ S_n$

Tags: group-theory

I try  this by following way,
Let  $H $ be the subgroup  generated by $(1, 2), (1, 2, 3,\dots .,n) $. How do I show, $H$ contain  elements $ (1, r) $  for $ r = 1, 2,...n$. Does there exist any trick to show it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $s = (1\;2)$ and $c = (1\;2\;3\;\ldots\;n)$ then $$c^{-i} s c^{i} = (i\;i+1)$$ and since you can create any permutation from transpositions, this gives the whole of $S_n$.

To verify this identity, see that $j$ gets mapped to $j-i \mod n$ then swapped only if it's 1 or 2, then $i$ is added back.

---

Also $c^{-(n-2)} s c^{n-1} = (1\;2\;3\;\ldots\;n-1)$

---

If we use $a^b$ short for $b^{-1} a b$ (the reason this is such a useful operation to do is that it preserves the length of the cycle) then consider

- $s$
- $(s^c)^s$
- $(((s^c)^s)^c)^s$
- ...

Comment: Nice work + 1...you certainly beat me too it!

Comment: Should be $(i+1  i+2)$ in equation 1?

Comment: I can see the product $c^{-i}sc^i$ doing some interesting things to $[n]$, but I’m not sure the identity $c^{-i}sc^i = (i,i+1)$ is correct? For example, I expect $(1,2,3,4,5)^{-2}(1,2)(1,2,3,4,5)^2 = (2,3)$ according to the formula, but it actually gives me $(4,5)$?

Comment: Would a more appropriate rule be $c^{-((n+1-i) \operatorname{mod}n)}sc^{(n+1-i)\operatorname{mod}n} = (i,i+1)$?

Answer (score 2):

We will show that every transposition can be generated from products of the two
permutations $(1, 2)$ and $(1, 2, . . . , n)$. This is achieved in $3$ separate steps

$1$. First observe,

$(1, 2, . . . , n)^{-1}(1, 2)(1, 2, . . . , n) = (2, 3)$

$(1, 2, . . . , n)^{-1}(2, 3)(1, 2, . . . , n) = (3, 4)$

$(1, 2, . . . , n)^{-1} (3, 4)(1, 2, . . . , n) = (4, 5)$

$(1, 2, . . . , n)^{-1}(n − 2, n − 1)(1, 2, . . . , n) = (n − 1, n)$

In short, transpositions of the form $(i, i + 1)$ have been obtained.

$2$. Thus,

$(1, 2)(2, 3)(1, 2) = (1, 3)$

$(1, 3)(3, 4)(1, 3) = (1, 4)$

$(1, 4)(4, 5)(1, 4) = (1, 5)$
.
.
.
$(1, n − 1)(n − 1, n)(1, n − 1) = (1, n)$
In short, transpositions of the form $(1, i)$ have been obtained.

$3$. Finally, $(1, i)(1, j)(i, 1) = (i, j)$ for$ i \neq j$

Hence, every transposition has been generated from $(1, 2)$ and $(1, 2, . . . , n)$, so these generate all of $S_n$